# php: "include" twice within div

Tags: php, function, html

file a.html

```
    <div id=1>
       <?php Include "a.php?parameter=1" ?>
    </div>

    <div id=2>
       <?php Include "a.php?parameter=2" ?>
    </div>
```

file  a.php:

```
    <? Php
    b;
    Function b {}
    ?>
```

calling a.html produces the error: "cannot redeclare `b()`" in div 2. The reason is easily understood - but what is the most efficient workaround?

Comment: Why are you including same file twice ?

Comment: Why are you including the same code twice? A properly structured function should be able to handle multiple inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including another PHP file doesn't fire off a new HTTP request. You cannot pass parameters to the included file like that. The text inside the quotes must resolve to a file on disk, including the `?parameter=1` part.

If you want to pass parameters to the included file, keep in mind that the current scope is available to the included code. You can assign values to global/local variables and then use them within the included file.

```
// run.php

<?php
    $name = 'Bob';
    include 'inc.php';
?>

// inc.php

<?php
    echo "Hi, $name!\n";
?>
```

**Update**

You cannot declare the same function more than once, even when using `include`. Instead, include the file that declares the function at the top of your page once. Use [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to ensure it happens only once and breaks if it cannot find the file. Then, anywhere you need the effects of the function, call it in your page's script without doing another include.

```
// run.php

<?php require_once 'sayhi.php'; ?>

<div id="1">
    <?php sayhi('Bob'); ?>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <?php sayhi('Frank'); ?>
</div>

// sayhi.php

<?php
    function sayhi($name) {
        echo "Hi, $name!\n";
    }
?>
```

This creates the desired output.

```
<div id="1">
    Hi, Bob!
</div>
<div id="2">
    Hi, Frank!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks; that's very helpful. However, my question was phrased ambiguosly. My issue is not so much about passing the parameters, but the fact that the function gets illegally redeclared. Let's assume I call A.PHP and B.PHP to yield text to two different divs within the same FILE.HTML. If A.PHP and B.PHP contain the same function, an error will be thrown - or not?

Comment: Yes, an error will be raised. You cannot declare two functions with the same name. Instead, declare the function in one file that's included once at the top and then call it wherever you need its effects, much as I did in the second example.

Comment: See my update for a full example. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Fantastic! That's very instructive and resolves the issue concisely and with admirable clarity! A million thanks!

Comment: A related thought. Does your example imply that it may be "best practice" to always wrap each PHP file into one big function that can be called from within divs, rather than calling it with a mess of GET_$ and argument stringed with ampersands? As has become painfully evident, I may have a PhD in molecular biology but my understanding of software is dismal...

Comment: The answer to what you're probably asking is "yes". This is the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and code-reuse in action. I wouldn't go so far as to say "each PHP file" will be one function since you'll want to group related functions into single files (or classes if using object-oriented programming). Though it's for Python instead of PHP (they are similar in many ways), I highly recommend the free [*How to Think Like a Computer Scientist*](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/) as a great programming book for beginners--even PhDs. :)

Answer (score 1):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

Please view information on the [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function.  The function b() should not have to be redeclared as it already exists. If you are trying to modify a variable that is set/passed to the function then you would include a parameter for the function that utilizes the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign parameters to the file, then instead of including the file twice, you can do two things instead,

1) include without any parameters and call the functions with an argument that would do the action for you
2) Dont include it anywhere, rather execute it whenever you want using exec or popen and pass your parameters that acceps as argv :)

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a very good way to resolve this (and many other) situations!